# Möbius transforms on the projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, projective-geometry

Let's suppose that I have a mapping
$$
\phi:\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1
$$
of degree two. How can I use Möbius transforms  to write this map as
$$
\phi([x:y])=\frac{y^2}{x^2}?
$$

I already know, from Hurwitz's formula, that $\phi$ has two ramification points, both of multiplicity two.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Roughly speaking: Mobius transformations are 3-transitive, so you can move the two ramification points in the source to 0 and $\infty$, and also their images to 0 and $\infty$; then convince yourself that the only degree-2 transformations ramified at 0 and $\infty$ are $z \mapsto \lambda z$ for nonzero $\lambda$.  But I'll let others flesh out (and correct as necessary) the details.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: In which part?  Actually, I know how to prove that Mobius transformations are 3-transitive (it's almost trivial).  But I'm not enough of an algebraic geometer to know of the top of my head to how finish the details of the argument.

Comment: Up to conjugating with a Moebius transformation, you can suppose that the two ramification points are at $0$ and at $\infty$. Now look at the affine piece $P^1\setminus\{\infty\}$: the restriction of the map there is a polynomial with exactly one ramification point. What can you say about it?

Comment: I was hoping to get the details of it. I can try to decode this later anyway.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I am sorry to bother you again with this question, but from what you told me I had the impression that at least there exists a Mobius transform that does what I want. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, as I said, you can use a Mobius transformation to move the ramification points to $0$ and $\infty$.  Then follow the hint from @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, with the correction that in my very first comment I meant "$z \mapsto \lambda z^2$".

Comment: Great! I'll try to work things out here and if I succeed I'll post as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: No success. I tried with an example (namely $\Phi([x:y])=\dfrac{x^2+xy}{y^2}$), found the ramification points, found the Mobius transforms that transport those points (and the images of them via $\Phi$) but still doesn't work and can't find those Mobius transforms that puts it in the form I want.

Comment: @Gustavo Marra: Could you please clarify what exactly you're trying to do? Specifically, do you want to: (i) conjugate $\phi$ into "standard form" (the squaring map) by a single Mobius transformation? (ii) Find _different_ Mobius transformations to pre-compose and post-compose with $\phi$ to get the standard form? (iii) Something else...? (i) appears to be impossible in general: The critical _points_ of the squaring map coincide with the critical _values_, but the same is not generally true of $\phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer has been re-written. It is essentially the argument given by Theo Johnson-Freyd in a comment, augmented by an explicit example.)

Suppose $\Phi : X \to Y$ is a degree-two morphism, where $X \cong Y \cong \mathbb{P}^1$.  Then, as the OP says, an argument based on Hurwitz's theorem tells us that $\Phi$ has two ramification points, each of multiplicity two.

If we let $z$ be an affine coordinate on $X$, and take for granted the well-known fact that Möbius transformations are two-transitive${}^1$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$, we can map the two ramification points to $z = \pm\infty$.  Similarly, if $w$ is an affine coordinate on $Y$, we can map their images to $w = \pm\infty$.

The morphism $\Phi$, restricted to the affine patch, becomes a map $\phi : \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, $w = \phi(z)$, which is generically two-to-one, but ramified at zero.  This can only be $w = \alpha z^2$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^*$.  Rescaling $w$ (which is a Möbius transformation fixing $0$ and $\infty$), we get $w = z^2$, which is what we wanted.

---

An example:

Let the morphism be given, as a map from homogeneous coordinates $[x:y]$ on $X$ to an affine coordinate $w$ on $Y$, as
$$
w = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy} ~.
$$
Introducing the affine coordinate $z = x/y$, this becomes
$$
w = z + \frac 1z~.
$$
Setting $dw/dz = 0$, we find the ramification points are $z = \pm 1$.  So the first thing to do is find a transformation which sends these to $0$ and $\infty$. Define
$$
z' = \frac{z+1}{z-1} ~.
$$
Now we find
$$
w = 2\left(1 + \frac{2}{z'^2 - 1}\right)~,
$$
hence
$$
\frac{w + 2}{w-2} = z'^2 ~.
$$
So the branch points are at $w = \pm 2$ (indeed, these points corresponds to the images of $z = \pm 1$; this is a simple consistency check).  The left-hand side of the above is precisely the Möbius transformation we need to send these points to $0$ and $\infty$; setting $w'$ equal to this expression, we have $w' = z'^2$, and are done.

${}^1$ In fact they are three-transitive, but we don't need this.

Comment: How did you get these transformations?

Comment: Also it should be $w\rightarrow w'+\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Also, the same technique does not work in several cases, as in $\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy}$ or $z+\dfrac{1}{z}$ in your notation.

Comment: @GustavoMarra: I will edit my answer.

Comment: I don't get where the expression $w = 2\left(1 + \frac{1}{z'^2 + 1}\right)$ came from

Comment: @GustavoMarra: invert the first transformation to find $z$ in terms of $z'$, then plug this into the expression for $w$, and do some re-arranging.

Comment: I think what in the same $w$ expression there is a minus missing

Comment: @GustavoMarra: I'm very sorry; I did the algebra quickly, and made a silly mistake. I will correct it.

Comment: Don't worry, I made the calculations myself and everything else is in order. Do you think we could discuss some generalization instead of working with examples?

Comment: @GustavoMarra: I've re-written my answer again, but all I can really do is regurgitate what was given in a comment, plus give the example to show how to do it in practice.